# Input field null on upload image in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am trying to upload image, on laravel. But when I try to upload image, the input field return null.

What is the solution for this problem ?

```
<form id="doctor" action="{{ route('doctors.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group"> 
      <label for="image" class="control-label">Doctor Picture</label>
      <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">
   </div>
</form>
```

Function

```
$doctor =  Doctor::create([ 
    'name' => $request->name,
    'address' => $request->address,
    'image' => $request->file('image')->store('images'),
    'visitting_card' => $request->file('visitting_card')->store('visitting_cards')
]);
```

Comment: Please share the html code

Comment: Please check, Your for has enctype attribute or not. For eg : enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: keep your html code and how you have called in controller @Hasinur Rahman

Comment: Ok, form is good, share controller's code also ?

Comment: <form id="doctor" action="{{ route('doctors.store') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">




 <div class="form-group"> 

  <label for="image" class="control-label">Doctor Picture</label>

  <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="form-control">

   </div>
</form>

Comment: laravel controlles code where you tried to store file, and update that code in your question, don't comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the right way.

Retrieving An Uploaded File in laravel

```
$file = Input::file('photo');
```

Determining If A File Was Uploaded in laravel

```
if (Input::hasFile('photo'))
{
   //
}
```